# Gmail Apps script function to display Browser MsgBox from GMail Addon

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I have the following working code which validates a list of recipients based on specific conditions. However, I'm looking to replace the resulting "Logger.log" actions with "Browser.msgbox" actions, and for some reason, GMail App Addons are not allowing me to do so:

```
function validateRecipients(e) {
  var toEmails = e.draftMetadata.toRecipients, ccEmails = e.draftMetadata.ccRecipients, bccEmails = e.draftMetadata.bccRecipients, domains = [], uniqueDomains = [];
  var allEmails = toEmails.concat(ccEmails, bccEmails);
  for (var i = 0; i < allEmails.length; i++) {
    domains[i] = allEmails[i].split("@").pop().split(".")[0]; 
  }  
  uniqueDomains = domains.filter(listUnique);
  if(uniqueDomains.length <= 2 && uniqueDomains.indexOf("verasafe") != -1) {
    Logger.log("This Message is Good to Go");
  }

  else if(uniqueDomains.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("This Message has no recipients");
  }

  else {
    Logger.log("Please Validate Receipients of this Message and Try again");
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible. There is no message box object available to you, and there is not a way of returning an evaluated JavaScript alert script either. Does this have to be a message box? Could you use something like a message in the side-bar?

Comment: Anything that alerts the user to the outcome, yes - Other than Logger.log

Comment: It really doesn't seem to be possible. Kind of surprising. An 'Are you sure' dialog box can be pretty essential sometimes - or just the ability to show a card in a popup. Shame :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Browser.msg` or any of the UI classes with Gmail.

However, there is a [new feature called `Card Service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service) that is meant to be used for the creation of UI for Gmail Addons.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer

Browser.msg can't be used on Gmail Add-ons, because, from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser

> This class provides access to dialog boxes specific to Google Sheets.

Comment: Yup, that's my problem :)

Comment: Then what is the dialog API we should use to prompt the user with a standard ok/cancel dialog within a GMail add-on (Google script) source?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could currently find is `notification` which shows a quick message at the bottom of the card (in Google's Material design it's called a [snackbar](https://material.io/components/snackbars)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/notification

Other than that you need to replace the card with a new one.

```
function _navigateToCard(card: GoogleAppsScript.Card_Service.Card, replace: boolean)
{
    var nav = CardService.newNavigation();

    replace ? nav.updateCard(card) : nav.pushCard(card)

    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(nav)
      .build();
}
```